# Module of finite projective dimesion contains a free module

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, gorenstein

Let $(R, m)$ be a Gorenstein local ring. $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module with $\dim M=\dim R$ and $\text{pd }M<\infty$. Then $M$ contains a free module $R^k$, such that $$0\longrightarrow R^k\longrightarrow M\longrightarrow N\longrightarrow0$$ is exact with $\dim N<\dim M=\dim R$.

It seems to me that $R^k$ in this case should come from the torsion free part of $M$, but I have no idea how to show this. I also guess this result hold when $R$ is a Cohen-Macaulay ring.

Comment: It holds actually for any local ring and comes from the following: Suppose $M$ has rank $r>0$, meaning $M \otimes_R Q(R)$ is a free $Q(R)$-module of rank $r$, where $Q(R)$ is the total quotient ring of $R$. Then there is an exact sequence $0 \to R^{\oplus r} \to M \to N \to 0$ where $\dim(N)<\dim(M)$. If you are not familiar with this fact, I'll let you think on how to prove it. It remains to also observe that any module of finite projective dimension has rank (Hint: rank is additive across short exact sequences).

Comment: @metalspringpro Thanks, I get in now.

Comment: @metalspringpro Can you write out the argument that this notion of rank is additive across short exact sequences? In particular, if $0 \rightarrow F_1 \rightarrow F_2 \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0$ is exact with $F_i$ free, why does $M$ necessarily have rank? (I see it when $R$ has no embedded primes, but not in the general case)

Comment: @BadamBaplan This is in fact Prop 1.4.5 from Bruns and Herzog's Cohen-Macaulay Rings. I found that my question actually was prop 1.4.3(b)

Comment: @Bromelain Thanks!